# JQuery, array problem

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json

It seems that the following code doesn't print anything, while, as you can see, it should.
Basically there are no errors reported by Firebug.

```
            var assign = {
                'href' : {
                    '.voteUp' : '?p=action&a=voteup&pid='+ value.PostPID,
                    '.voteDown' : '?p=action&a=votedown&pid='+ value.PostPID,
                    '.postImage a': '?p=user&uid='+ value.UserUID
                },

                'src' : {
                    '.postImage img' : value.UserImage
                },

                'html' : {
                    '.repCount' : value.PostRep,
                    '.postInfo .rep': value.UserRep,
                    '.postInfo .name': value.UserName,
                    '.postInfo .time': value.PostTime,
                    '.postMessage' : value.PostText
                }
            };

            $.each(assign, function(type, data) {
                switch (type)
                {
                    case 'html':
                        $.each(data, function(handler, value) {
                            $('#'+ value.PostPID +' '+ handler).html(value);
                        });
                    break;

                    case 'href':
                    case 'src':
                        $.each(data, function(handler, value) {
                            $('#'+ value.PostPID +' '+ handler).attr(type, value);
                        });
                    break;
                }
            });
```

This is part of other code, but the rest of the script works well (for example, after this code there is a function that `fadeIn` the contents). If you cannot find anything bad here, please comment above and i'll add the entire script.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the objects  have a `PostPID` property.

Since `value` represents the object referenced b `html`, `src` etc., you need to use a *property* in those objects, to get the proper value.

For example:

```
case 'html':
    $.each(data, function(handler, value) {
        $('#'+ value['.repCount']+' '+ handler).html(value);
    });
break;
```

Or perhaps you wanted the *other* `value` identifier (the source of which is not included in the question).

In that case, rename the parameter for the `$.each()` handler to something else.

```
case 'html':
       // renamed value paramter---v---to make the previous "value" accessible
    $.each(data, function(handler, v) {
        $('#'+ value.PostPID+' '+ handler).html(v['.repCount']);
  // original----^        "each" parameter------^
    });
break;
```